# What fields available in DatabaseError? (django/python)

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error `DatabaseError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')` which I want to handle by restarting the operation.

How do I make sure I only restart when it is the specific deadlock error, i. e. with the code `1213`, rather than any database error?

I cannot find what fields are available in the `DatabaseError` exception object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dir()` built in to see all the attributes of an object.

```
>>> from django.db.utils import DatabaseError
>>> dir(DatabaseError)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__getslice__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__setstate__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__unicode__',
 '__weakref__',
 'args',
 'message']
```

As you can see, you might find something useful in the args or message attributes. To investigate what these attributes return, you should catch the exception with a `DatabaseError`, print out the attributes we're interest in and then invoke the [python interactive debugger](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/pdb.html):

```
try:
    # whatever code is raising your exception
except DatabaseError as e:
    print e.args
    print e.message
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    # then look at the output to see if you can find something useful
```

To understand where the `args` attribute comes from, we need to look at the `BaseException` [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.BaseException) which say

> args -
>   The tuple of arguments given to the exception constructor. Some
>   built-in exceptions (like IOError) expect a certain number of
>   arguments and assign a special meaning to the elements of this tuple,
>   while others are usually called only with a single string giving an
>   error message

Hopefully there will be something of note in one of those attributes which you can check against.